# I am writing an insert and remove function with switch statement in c++ , all other functions are working except insert,remove, kth item

Tags: c++

This is an interactive test program for the List class as provided by the LinkedList.h.

The program responds to commands from the user to exercise commands as described in the menu() function.
The program will read and respond to commands that the user enters to manipulate an ordered list.

INPUT- The program reads commands to manipulate its List. These commands consist of a letter sometimes followed by an integer. For example, the command "i 25" tells the program to insert the value 25 into the List.

OUTPUT-The program writes instructions and a menu of commands to the terminal, it prompts for the user's input, and it outputs lists and elements of lists.

ERRORS-The program may assume that the input the user provides is correct; except that it will report if a position is beyond the end of a list (See the example below). Otherwise, it need not detect any errors.

This program responds to commands the user enters to manipulate an ordered list of integers, which is initially empty. In the following commands, k is a position in the list, and v is an integer.

```
 e -- Re-initialize the list to be empty.
    i v -- Insert the value v into the list.
    r v -- Remove the value v from the list.
    m -- Is the list empty?
    l -- Report the length of the list.
    p v -- Is the value v present in the list?
    k k1 -- Report the k1th value in the list.
    w -- Write out the list.
    h -- See this menu.
    q -- Quit.
```

header file

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H

#include <cstdlib>                 // Provides size_t
#include <iostream>                // Provides ostream

using namespace std;

  class List
  {
    public:
    // TYPEDEF
      typedef int Item;                   // What can go in a list

    // CONSTRUCTORS
      List( ) { first = NULL; }           // Inline
      List( const List& source );         // Copy constructor

    // DESTRUCTOR
      ~List( );

    // MODIFICATION MEMBER FUNCTIONS
      void make_empty ( );
      void insert ( const Item& entry );
      void remove ( const Item& target );
      void operator = ( const List& source );

    // CONSTANT MEMBER FUNCTIONS
      bool isEmptyList( ) const {return first==NULL;} // Inline
      int length( ) const;
      bool present ( const Item& target ) const;
      Item kth (int k ) const;
      void quit() const;

    // FRIEND FUNCTION for the List class:
      friend std::ostream& operator << ( std::ostream& out_s,
                                         const List& l );
    private:
    // DATA MEMBERS
      struct Node
      {
        Item data;
        Node *next;
      };
      Node *first;
cpp file
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

  // Default constructor is inline.

 // Copy constructor
  List::List(const List& source)
  {
    Node* p;       // Will traverse the source List.
    Node* last;    // Will always point to the new List's last Node.

    if ( source.first == NULL )   // If the source list is empty ...
      first = NULL;
    else
    {
      first = get_node(source.first->data,NULL);  // Copy the first Node.
      last = first;
      p = source.first->next;
      while ( p != NULL )                         // Copy remaining Nodes.
      {
        last->next = get_node(p->data,NULL);
        last = last->next;
        p = p->next;
      }
    }
  }

   // Destructor
  List::~List( )
  {
    Node* temp;

    while ( first != NULL )
    {
      temp = first;
      first = first -> next;
      delete temp;
    }
}  // end destructor


  // Modification member functions
  void List::make_empty ( )
  {
    Node* temp;

    while ( first != NULL )
    {
      temp = first;
      first = first -> next;
      delete temp;
    }
  }

  void List::insert ( const Item& entry )
  {
    Node *prev;

    assert ( ! present(entry) );

    if ( first == NULL || entry < first->data )
      first = get_node(entry,first);
    else
    {
      prev = first;
      while ( prev->next != NULL && prev->next->data < entry )
      prev = prev->next;
      prev->next = get_node(entry,prev->next);
    }
}  // end insert

  void List::remove ( const Item& target )
  {
    Node *temp;
    Node *prev;

    assert ( present(target) );

    prev = first;
    if ( prev->data == target )
    {
      first = first->next;
      delete prev;
    }
    else
    {
      while ( prev->next != NULL && prev->next->data < target )
      prev = prev->next;
      temp = prev->next;
      prev->next = temp->next;
      delete temp;
   }
}  // end remove

// Constant member functions
  int List::length( ) const
  {
    Node *p;
    int k;
    k= 0;
    for(p = first; p != NULL; p = p->next)
    {
     ++k;
      p=p->next ;
    }
    return k;
   } // end length



   bool List::present ( const Item& target ) const
   {
    Node *p = first;
    for(p!=NULL && p->data!=target;
          p=p->next;) // The loop's body is empty.
    {
    return ( p != NULL );
    }

   }

 void List::quit() const
 { return; }

  List::Item List::kth ( int k ) const
  {
    Node *p;
    int i;

    assert ( 1 <= k && k <= length() );

    p = first;
    for (int i=1; i<k; ++i)
      p = p->next;
    return p->data;
  }

  // Friend Function
  // This function writes out the list
  ostream& operator << ( ostream& out_s, const List& l )
  {
    List::Node *p;
    p = l.first;
   while(p != NULL )
   {
      out_s << p->data << " ";
      p = p->next;
   }
    return out_s;      //return output stream.
  }

  // Private function
  List::Node* List::get_node ( const Item& entry, Node* link )
  {
    Node *temp;
    temp = new Node;
    temp->data = entry;
    temp->next = link;
    return temp;
  }

    // PRIVATE FUNCTION
      Node* get_node ( const Item& entry, Node* link );
  };
#endif

main.cpp
#include "LinkedList.h"// ADT list operations
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cassert>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

  char command;                // Each command letter
  int v;                       // The value to be inserted
  char e, i, r, m, l, p, w, h, q;
  int k;                      // position in the list
  List n;                 // An ordered list.

  void menu()
  //Postcondition: A menu of commands and instructions
  //for their use has been written to out.
{
  cout << endl;
  cout << "This program responds to commands the user enters to" << endl;
  cout << "manipulate ordered LinkedList which are initially empty." << endl;
  cout << "In the following commands, v is any integer, and" << endl;
  cout << "integers from 0 to " << endl << endl;
  cout << "  e    -- Re-initialize list n to be empty." << endl;
  cout << "  i v  -- Insert the value v into list n." << endl;
  cout << "  r v  -- Remove the value v from list n." << endl;
  cout << "  m   -- Report is the List n empty." << endl;
  cout << "  l -- Report the length of the list n." << endl;
  cout << "  p v -- Is the value present in the list n." << endl;
  cout << "  k   -- Report the kth value in the List n." << endl;
  cout << "  w  -- Write out the contents of LinkedList n." << endl;
  cout << "  h -- See this menu." << endl;
  cout << "  q -- Quit the program." << endl << endl;
}

 int main()
 {

  menu();                    //show the menu
  do
  {
    cout << "--> ";            // Issue a prompt.
    cin >> command;            // Read a command letter.
    switch ( command )         // Carry out the command.
    {
      case 'e': n.make_empty();
                cout << "The list is empty." << endl;
                break;
      case 'i': cin >> v ;
                n.insert(v);
                cout << "The new item is inserted into list." << n << endl;
                break;
      case 'r': cin >> v ;
                n.remove(v);
                cout << "The new item is removed from the list." << n << endl;
                break;
      case 'm': if (n.isEmptyList() ==true){
                    cout << "The list is empty." << endl;
                }
                else{
                    cout << "The list is NOT empty." << endl;
                }
                break;
     case 'l':  n.length();
                cout<< "The length of the list is "<< n.length()<<endl;
                break;
     case 'p':  cin >> v ;
                if (n.present(v)==true){
                    cout << "The value" << v << "is present in the list." << endl;
                }
                else{
                    cout << "The value" << v << "is Not present in the list." << endl;
                }
                break;
      case 'k': cin >> v;
                cout << "LinkedList " << setw(1) << n << " contains "
                     << setw(1) << n.kth(k) << " items." << endl;
                cout << "The " << v << "is Not present in the list." << endl;
                break;
      case 'w': cout << "List:" <<n<< endl;
                break;
      case 'h': menu();
                cout << "The progam menu is shown." << endl;
                break;
      case 'q': n.quit();
                cout << "The program is quiting." << endl;
                break;
      default: ;               // Null statement for an incorrect command
    }
    } while (command != 'q');
 }
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code? Please provide a [mre] with the expected output, actual output and any error messages

Comment: Why don't you run your insert code in a debugger, step through it 1 line at a time and see what it does.